# Do not sort variable in lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn, plotnine

I'm trying to make a plot of mean slope x elevation for a given area, but I'm a bit lost with the sorting of data in plotnine. The dataframe has 3 cols: Elevation (already ordered from low to high), Slope (unordered, must remain as is), DEM (used for grouping). When ploting in seaborn, I can set the `sort` option and it works fine:

```
sns.lineplot(data=pd_areas, x="Slope", y="Elevation", hue="DEM", sort=False)
```

[seaborn plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUQY1.png)

but with plotnine, the values are sorted and the result is wrong:

```
(p9.ggplot(pd_areas)
+p9.geom_line(mapping=p9.aes(x='Slope', y='Elevation', color='DEM', group='DEM'))
)
```

[plotnine plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inYVc.png)

Sorry for not providing an MVE, but I can't send the DEMs at this moment.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`.